# Query performance redifinition

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

I'm using Oracle database: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production.
I have this query that is not very performance:

```
SELECT COUNT (1)
  FROM SGSS.MTLIDO L2
 WHERE        L2.LIDODOID IN
                 (SELECT DISTINCT L1.LIDODOID
                    FROM SGSS.MTREXT R1
                         INNER JOIN SGSS.MTDEXT D1
                            ON (    D1.DEXTCDDE = R1.REXTCDDE
                                AND D1.DEXTNEXT = R1.REXTNEXT)
                         INNER JOIN SGSS.MTLIDO L1
                            ON (    D1.DEXTCDDE = L1.LIDOCDDE
                                AND D1.DEXTNUSI = L1.LIDONUSI
                                AND D1.DEXTNUAU = L1.LIDONUAU
                                AND D1.DEXTNUGR = L1.LIDONUGR
                                AND D1.DEXTTIEN = L1.LIDOTIEN)
                   WHERE     R1.REXTCDDE = 1
                         AND R1.REXTSIMC = '1'
                         AND R1.REXTNREC = '1')
          AND (NOT EXISTS
                  (SELECT 1
                     FROM SGSS.MTDEXT D2
                          INNER JOIN SGSS.MTEXAS ON (EXASNEXT = DEXTNEXT)
                          INNER JOIN SGSS.MTREXT R2
                             ON (    D2.DEXTCDDE = R2.REXTCDDE
                                 AND D2.DEXTNEXT = R2.REXTNEXT)
                    WHERE     D2.DEXTCDDE = L2.LIDOCDDE
                          AND D2.DEXTNUSI = L2.LIDONUSI
                          AND D2.DEXTNUAU = L2.LIDONUAU
                          AND D2.DEXTNUGR = L2.LIDONUGR
                          AND D2.DEXTTIEN = L2.LIDOTIEN
                          AND r2.REXTESTA NOT IN ('03')))
       OR EXISTS
             ( (SELECT 1
                  FROM SGSS.MTDEXT D2
                       INNER JOIN SGSS.MTREXT R2
                          ON (    D2.DEXTCDDE = R2.REXTCDDE
                              AND D2.DEXTNEXT = R2.REXTNEXT)
                 WHERE     D2.DEXTCDDE = L2.LIDOCDDE
                       AND D2.DEXTNUSI = L2.LIDONUSI
                       AND D2.DEXTNUAU = L2.LIDONUAU
                       AND D2.DEXTNUGR = L2.LIDONUGR
                       AND D2.DEXTTIEN = L2.LIDOTIEN
                       AND r2.REXTESTA NOT IN ('08',
                                               '04',
                                               '03',
                                               '09')));
```

The explain plan:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                        | Name         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                 |              |     1 |    32 |   345M  (1)| 03:09:55 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE                  |              |     1 |    32 |            |          |
|*  2 |   FILTER                         |              |       |       |            |          |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL             | MTLIDO       |    49M|  1499M|   408K  (4)| 00:00:14 |
|   4 |    NESTED LOOPS                  |              |     1 |    45 |     7   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |     NESTED LOOPS                 |              |     1 |    45 |     7   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | MTDEXT       |     1 |    32 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  7 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN           | MTDEXT_TESTE |     1 |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  8 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN           | PK_MTREXT    |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  9 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | MTREXT       |     1 |    13 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  10 |    NESTED LOOPS                  |              |     1 |    91 |    10   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  11 |     NESTED LOOPS                 |              |     1 |    91 |    10   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  12 |      NESTED LOOPS                |              |     1 |    59 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 13 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN           | MTREXT08     |     1 |    27 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 14 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| MTDEXT       |     1 |    32 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 15 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN          | MTDEXT04     |    13 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 16 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN            | MTLIDO03     |     1 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 17 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | MTLIDO       |     1 |    32 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  18 |    NESTED LOOPS                  |              |     1 |    51 |     9   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  19 |     NESTED LOOPS                 |              |     1 |    51 |     9   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  20 |      NESTED LOOPS                |              |     1 |    38 |     7   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 21 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| MTDEXT       |     1 |    32 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 22 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN          | MTDEXT_TESTE |     1 |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 23 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN           | MTEXAS_01    |     1 |     6 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 24 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN           | PK_MTREXT    |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 25 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | MTREXT       |     1 |    13 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter( EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM "SGSS"."MTREXT" "R2","SGSS"."MTDEXT" "D2" WHERE 
              "D2"."DEXTNUAU"=:B1 AND "D2"."DEXTNUSI"=:B2 AND "D2"."DEXTCDDE"=:B3 AND 
              "D2"."DEXTNUGR"=:B4 AND "D2"."DEXTTIEN"=:B5 AND "D2"."DEXTNEXT"="R2"."REXTNEXT" AND 
              "R2"."REXTCDDE"=:B6 AND "R2"."REXTESTA"<>'04' AND "R2"."REXTESTA"<>'09' AND 
              "R2"."REXTESTA"<>'03' AND "R2"."REXTESTA"<>'08' AND "D2"."DEXTCDDE"="R2"."REXTCDDE") OR  
              EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM "SGSS"."MTLIDO" "L1","SGSS"."MTDEXT" "D1","SGSS"."MTREXT" "R1" 
              WHERE "R1"."REXTNREC"=1 AND "R1"."REXTSIMC"='1' AND "R1"."REXTCDDE"=1 AND 
              "D1"."DEXTNEXT"="R1"."REXTNEXT" AND "D1"."DEXTCDDE"=1 AND 
              "D1"."DEXTTIEN"="L1"."LIDOTIEN" AND "D1"."DEXTNUGR"="L1"."LIDONUGR" AND 
              "D1"."DEXTNUAU"="L1"."LIDONUAU" AND "D1"."DEXTNUSI"="L1"."LIDONUSI" AND 
              "L1"."LIDOCDDE"=1 AND "L1"."LIDODOID"=:B7) AND  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM 
              "SGSS"."MTREXT" "R2","SGSS"."MTEXAS" "MTEXAS","SGSS"."MTDEXT" "D2" WHERE 
              "D2"."DEXTNUAU"=:B8 AND "D2"."DEXTNUSI"=:B9 AND "D2"."DEXTCDDE"=:B10 AND 
              "D2"."DEXTNUGR"=:B11 AND "D2"."DEXTTIEN"=:B12 AND "EXASNEXT"="DEXTNEXT" AND 
              "D2"."DEXTNEXT"="R2"."REXTNEXT" AND "R2"."REXTCDDE"=:B13 AND "R2"."REXTESTA"<>'03' AND 
              "D2"."DEXTCDDE"="R2"."REXTCDDE"))
   6 - filter("D2"."DEXTNUGR"=:B1 AND "D2"."DEXTTIEN"=:B2)
   7 - access("D2"."DEXTCDDE"=:B1 AND "D2"."DEXTNUSI"=:B2 AND "D2"."DEXTNUAU"=:B3)
   8 - access("D2"."DEXTNEXT"="R2"."REXTNEXT")
   9 - filter("R2"."REXTCDDE"=:B1 AND "R2"."REXTESTA"<>'04' AND "R2"."REXTESTA"<>'09' 
              AND "R2"."REXTESTA"<>'03' AND "R2"."REXTESTA"<>'08' AND "D2"."DEXTCDDE"="R2"."REXTCDDE")
  13 - access("R1"."REXTCDDE"=1 AND "R1"."REXTSIMC"='1' AND "R1"."REXTNREC"=1)
  14 - filter("D1"."DEXTCDDE"=1)
  15 - access("D1"."DEXTNEXT"="R1"."REXTNEXT")
  16 - access("L1"."LIDOCDDE"=1 AND "D1"."DEXTNUSI"="L1"."LIDONUSI" AND 
              "D1"."DEXTNUAU"="L1"."LIDONUAU" AND "D1"."DEXTNUGR"="L1"."LIDONUGR" AND 
              "D1"."DEXTTIEN"="L1"."LIDOTIEN")
  17 - filter("L1"."LIDODOID"=:B1)
  21 - filter("D2"."DEXTNUGR"=:B1 AND "D2"."DEXTTIEN"=:B2)
  22 - access("D2"."DEXTCDDE"=:B1 AND "D2"."DEXTNUSI"=:B2 AND "D2"."DEXTNUAU"=:B3)
  23 - access("EXASNEXT"="DEXTNEXT")
  24 - access("D2"."DEXTNEXT"="R2"."REXTNEXT")
  25 - filter("R2"."REXTCDDE"=:B1 AND "R2"."REXTESTA"<>'03' AND 
              "D2"."DEXTCDDE"="R2"."REXTCDDE")
```

Maybe the query have other kind of problems, but I'm focused in the `OR` statement. This is where the problem lies.

How can I transform this `OR` statement and improve the performance? I've tried to change this with using `MINUS` condition but I couldn't retrieve the same results or the results that I have: count the number of records with these conditions.

Any suggestion it will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Filipe

Comment: You need (composite) indexes on all the tables used for the joins.

Comment: did you created any composited index on your tables? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28274/data_acc.htm#i2773

Comment: And I have. All tables have composite indexes with the columns referenced. Even MTLIDO table but doesn't used here: LIDOCDDE, LIDONUSI, LIDONUAU, LIDONUGR, LIDOTIEN. See the Explain Plan and the index use.

Comment: Part of the problem might also be the lack of brackets around the where clause to determine where the OR clause belongs. Is it `where L2.LIDODOID IN (...) AND (not exists (...) or exists (...))` or `where (ld.lidodoid in (...) and not exists (...)) or exists (...)`?

Comment: Hi Boneist. It's the first one `where L2.LIDODOID IN (...) AND (not exists (...) or exists (...))`. The problem is that I have one NOT EXISTS and EXIST with the OR clause.